# generic xinput controller ubuntu

Tags: xinput, gamepad, xbox-360

I would like to use my Trust GXT 590 BOSI on my Linux machine. I use Ubuntu 18.04.5
The controller is said to support Android and Windows X and D input. It has a USB dongle. I've tried it with my Android phone, it works fine. I've tried xboxdrv and sometimes I can get it to register as an Xbox 360 controller:

Controller:        Microsoft X-Box 360 pad
Vendor/Product:    045e:028e
USB Path:          001:026
Controller Type:   Xbox360

Your Xbox/Xbox360 controller should now be available as:
/dev/input/js0
/dev/input/event24

xboxdrv 0.8.8 is the version

If I open controller settings in Steam, it also shows an Xbox360 controller detected. However when I try to use it in games or try to calibrate it in Steam, nothing's happening. I can't get any input from the controller.

I am a Linux noob, I might have missed an important step or done something wrong.
What I did:
Plugged the dongle into the back of my PC. Turned on the controller as X input. Lights on it flashed for a bit, then stayed lit (guessing it connected).
installed xboxdrv. blacklisted xpad. ran xboxdrv with sudo.
also, I checked, I don't have ubuntu-xboxdrv installed.

Can anyone help me diagnose this issue? I'd really appreciate it. Thanks in advance.

Comment: xpad should be fine for this device in XInput mode since it pretends to be an official Xbox 360 controller. Possibly the device doesn't behave exactly like an Xbox 360 controller and it's tripping up xpad and xboxdrv. Try re-enabling xpad and check the dmesg logs to see if you get an error when connecting the device. You could also try using it in one of its other modes (DInput or Android Bluetooth). These will use hid-input instead of xpad and may work better if you're hitting an xpad-specific issue.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your reply

Uninstalled xboxdrv, reinstalled xpad
Android bluetooth does not work. The other 2, D and X connect to the PC. Trouble is, it keeps connecting and reconnecting. Steam recognizes it, Xbox360 controller flashes up, then goes away. ever 2 seconds or so.
I looked at the dmesg logs, gave me this message about a 100 times:

xpad 3-2:1.0: xpad_try_sending_next_out_packet - usb_submit_urb failed with result -19

Googled the error, but couldn't find any solutions to it.

Comment: When I try listing devices with lsusb, I get 3 different readings on bus 003:
ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
ID 045e:028e Microsoft Corp. Xbox360 Controller
ID 2563:0537
Depending on the time the command was sent. So there are 2 devices that keep connecting ad reconnecting for some reason.